# How to wait for on a Task Completion Asynchronously

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, wait

I am writing a piece of code that triggers multiple tasks, and at the end I need to wait on a task to finish to move ahead.

Sample Code --

```
var taskToWaitOn = Task.Factory.StartNew(Method1);
Task.Factory.StartNew(Method2);
Task.Factory.StartNew(Method3);

taskToWaitOn.Wait();
```

Here if I wait on `taskToWaitOn` I am actually blocking a thread and hence in a 4 thread processor I am losing 25% of processing power.

Is there a way by which I can wait on this task in an Asynchronous Manner wherein, thread actually doesn't gets blocked on wait and is free to process other logic.

Comment: Just use `await`: `await taskToWaitOn;`

Comment: No, you're not wasting a core on the CPU. If a CPU core isn't busy then the OS will try to find it something else to do pending the thread becoming unblocked.

Comment: Can you explain how you "need to wait" and "doesn't gets blocked on wait" at the same time?

Comment: logic needs to wait for something to finish, but processor need not block it self and must keep itself free for other tasks

Answer (score -1):

Using async/await keys will do what you want to achieve.

[The Task asynchronous programming model in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

```
public async Task testMethod() {
    callToSyncMethod(); // This will block the thread
    await callToAsyncMethod; // This will not
    callToAnotherSyncMethod(); // This will block but executed after the async is complete
}
```

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question. Saying "will do what you want to achieve" is not an explanation. Your code also doesn't seem to match what the OP is asking for.

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question, read it again and maybe you will have a better luck next time. PS: I included a link to the full oficial explanation from MS.